# Computing pixel's screen position in a vertex shader: right or wrong?

Tags: hlsl, vertex, fragment-shader, interpolation

I am building a deferred rendering engine and I have a question. The article I took the sample code from suggested computing screen position of the pixel as follows:

```
VertexShaderFunction()
{
    ...
    output.Position = mul(worldViewProj, input.Position);
    output.ScreenPosition = output.Position;
}

PixelShaderFunction()
{
    input.ScreenPosition.xy /= input.ScreenPosition.w;
    float2 TexCoord = 0.5f * (float2(input.ScreenPosition.x,-input.ScreenPosition.y) + 1);
    ...
}
```

The question is what if I compute the position in the vertex shader (which should optimize the performance as VSF is launched significantly less number of times than PSF) would I get the per-vertex lighting insted. Here is how I want to do this:

```
VertexShaderFunction()
{
    ...
    output.Position = mul(worldViewProj, input.Position);
    output.ScreenPosition.xy = output.Position / output.Position.w;
}

PixelShaderFunction()
{
    float2 TexCoord = 0.5f * (float2(input.ScreenPosition.x,-input.ScreenPosition.y) + 1);
    ...
}
```

What exactly happens with the data I pass from VS to PS? How exactly is it interpolated? Will it give me the right per-pixel result in this case? I tried launching the game both ways and saw no visual difference. Is my assumption right?

Thanks.

P.S. I am optimizing the point light shader, so I actually pass a sphere geometry into the VS.

Solution:

```
struct PSInput
{
    float2 vPos : VPOS;
};

PixelShaderFunction(PSInput input)
{
    float2 ScrPos = input.vPos*halfPixel*2;

        //The correct Screen Space Texture Coordinates.
    float2 TexCoord = ScrPos + halfPixel;

    //Bonus: getting the world position.
    ScrPos = ScrPos*2 - 1;
    ScrPos = float2(ScrPos.x, -ScrPos.y);

    float4 position;
    position.xy = ScrPos;
    position.z = depthVal; // Read from the depth map.
    position.w = 1.0f;

    position = mul(position, InvertViewProjection);
    position /= position.w;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using hlsl I presume you use DirectX. You can use the input semantic VPOS (DX9) or SV_Position (DX>=10):
[MSDN - VPOS & SV_POSITION semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#VPOS)

When you pass the render target resolution reciprocal one mad is sufficient to construct the screen space uv for every type of geometry.

---

You can not simply do what you proposed as the interpolation does a perspective correction. In SM4 you can deactivate this for a single fragment shader input by setting the interpolation modifier to `noperspective`:
[MSDN - InterpolationModifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I did not use this method but it should work. Using the semantic is the easier and probably equally performant way.

---

A simple optimization for your code is replacing

```
float2 TexCoord = 0.5f * (float2(input.ScreenPosition.x,-input.ScreenPosition.y) + 1);
```

by

```
float2 TexCoord = 0.5f * float2(input.ScreenPosition.x,-input.ScreenPosition.y) + 0.5f;
```

this should ensure that a mad instruction is used instead of two seperate instructions.

Comment: I have just read about vPos in another article. Yes this is exactly what I need. I am using XNA -> SM 3.0, so I cannot employ your second suggestion :(.

Comment: Thanks for the non-perspective hint _"noperspective"_. It solved my issue...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it you will get a optimized gain from this. But to answer your question, that looks a bit funky. rather do it like this :

Setup a quad with the vertex positions from -1 to 1 in xy.
In the pixelshader just simply pass the input position as the SV_Position. no need for projection multiplications.

And for uvs, do the following equation.
texCoord = ( input.pos + 1.0f ) * 0.5f;
-1 + 1 -> 0 -> 0 * 0.5 = 0
1 + 1 -> 2 -> 2 * 0.5 = 1
And from there you have the basic 0->1 uvset.

This is super simple and should be super fast to.

Comment: I did not mention that I was optimizing for a point light. I actually pass a sphere geometry to the shader. The directional light shader that does use the quad computes uvs even better than you propose - it set's the quad vertices to 0,1.

Comment: well, it´s depending how you map it i guess. Well, you mention Defferd rendering engine, so i assumed you where asking about the defferd rendering pass.